# Partial match from string array

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a string array that looks like this:

```
string[] userFile = new string[] { "JohnDoe/23521/1", "JaneDoe/35232/4", ... };
```

I'm trying the following but this will only return exact matches.  I want to be able to return a match if I am searching for "23521".

```
var stringToCheck = "23521";

if (userFile.Any(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s)))
{
    // ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Contains()` call should be the other way round:

```
if (userFile.Any(s => s.Contains(stringToCheck)))
```

You want to check whether *any* string `s` in your `userFile` string array contains `stringToCheck`.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I now select the whole string and then check if the third item in the string (the number after the second delimiter) is equal to a value.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Not sure what you mean - or do you mean just `if(userFile[2] == stringToCheck)` ?

Comment: if (userFile.Any(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s))) ... if yes now check if the number after the second "/" in "JohnDoe/23521/1" is for example greater than 0 and then put that number into a variable.

Comment: You have to iterate over the items that fit the condition - `foreach(var matchingItem in userFile.Where(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s)))` then you can use `matchingItem.Split('/')`  - look up the methods on msdn

Answer (score 1):

if (userFile.Any(s => s.Contains(stringToCheck)))

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the string in the array contains the check string, not the other way around:

```
userFile.Any(s => s.Contains(stringToCheck))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems like a better choice:

```
if (userFile.Any(s => s.Contains(stringToCheck)))
```